# linear-gradient in scss with dynamic percentages

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I want to make a progress bar with background linear-gradient and use pre-defined theme colors in scss in vue. Such as:

```css
.progress{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $start-color 0%, $start-color 50%, $end-color 50%, $end-color 100%);
}
```

`50%` is dynamic changed by code in vue. If I write the style in `:style="{}"` then I can't use the pre-defined scss color `$start-color` and `$end-color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `:export` block from Interoperable CSS under CSS modules.

As an example consider the below given extracts, first in your sass file that has colors defined (say colors.scss):

```
$primaryColor: #fcf5ed;
$secondaryColor: #402f2b;

:export {
    primaryColor: $primaryColor;
    darkColor: $secondaryColor;
}
```

With that setup along with your style loaders (which you currently must have setup) you can just import the file like usual js modules like below in your Vue application:

```
import colorVariables from 'colors.scss'

colorVariables.primaryColor // => Will now have the value of the color as a string.
```

Now you can just use the :style binding of the Vue to define the linear-gradient. You can read more on `export` in the following link : [Interoperable CSS - :export](https://github.com/css-modules/icss#export) under CSS modules.